# How to make "connection" between two mixers in Java?

Tags: java, audio, connection, javasound

I understand, how to convert `AudioInputStream` from one format to another. Now, when I have stream converted, how to write it to matching `SourceDataLine` I have?

Just loop over `read()` and `write()` methods? Or there are better premade methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Usually done in a while loop with a boolean to allow a means of stopping via an "external" thread.

There is a good example in the Java Tutorials, under the heading "Using a SourceDataLine".
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html

There are extra steps for opening and closing the lines, but the tutorial covers this as well.